# How do I configure a bridged network for Docker?

Tags: networking, docker

I'm new to Docker (have been working with KVM earlier). The first problem I ran in to was how to configure a bridged network in Docker. I would to have a similiar configuration as a KVM bridged network. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
docker run --network=host
```

But if what you want is to access your container from outside use the port mapping option.

```
docker run -p 80:80
```

You will access your container using the host ip and the port you specified.

Docker internally in linux use iptables to redirect the traffic from your host to the container.

Regards

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Lets say that i run a ubuntu-container, i want it to be visible in my home Network. How do I do that and make it secured? @Carlos Rafael Ramirez